# JSON to HTML using JSON.parse undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

When trying to parse the JSON

```
[{"title":"First Item","href":"first","children":[{"title":"Sub First Item","href":"sub"}]},{"title":"Second Item","href":"home"}]
```

into a list for navigation its just returning undefined.

I was using code from another answer which was working fine with hardcoded JSON but when using it from a textbox (as its going to be generated using jquery.nestable.js) it just gived undefined and i cant see why, ive tried escaping the quotation marks too but no luck there.

```
function convertNav(){
    var data = document.getElementById('jsonNav').value;
    var jsn = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('jsonNav').value);
    var parseJsonAsHTMLTree = function(jsn){
    var result = '';
    if(jsn.title && jsn.children){
        result += '<li><a href="' + jsn.href + '">' + jsn.title + '</a><ul>';        

        for(var i in jsn.children) {            
            result += parseJsonAsHTMLTree(jsn.children[i]);            
        }

        result += '</ul></li>';        
    }
    else { 
        result += '<li><a href="' + jsn.href + '">' + jsn.title + '</a></li>'; 
    }

    return result + '';    
}

var result = '<ul>'+parseJsonAsHTMLTree(jsn)+'</ul>';
document.getElementById('convertedNav').value = result;
}
```

Ive put it in a jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/nfdz1jnx/

Comment: You have an array of objects. `if (jsn[0].title ...)`

Comment: Yes, the issue here is that your data object is an array, so you need to do this for each item in the array. Now you need to see if you want to treat each item in the array as it's own list or list item. as @MarcB noted, you could hard code this as: var result = '<ul>'+parseJsonAsHTMLTree(jsn[0])+parseJsonAsHTMLTree(jsn[1])+'</ul>';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code handles only a single Javascript object but, according to your code, all nodes and sub-nodes are wrapped inside Javascript arrays. You can use `Array.prototype.forEach` to handle the array objects.

Sample code follows.

```js
function convertNav() {
  var data = document.getElementById('seriaNav').value;
  var jsn = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('seriaNav').value);
  var parseJsonAsHTMLTree = function(jsn) {
    var result = '';
    jsn.forEach(function(item) {
      if (item.title && item.children) {
        result += '<li><a href="' + item.href + '">' + item.title + '</a><ul>';

        result += parseJsonAsHTMLTree(item.children);

        result += '</ul></li>';
      } else {
        result += '<li><a href="' + item.href + '">' + item.title + '</a></li>';
      }
    });

    return result + '';
  };

  var result = '<ul>' + parseJsonAsHTMLTree(jsn) + '</ul>';
  document.getElementById('convertedNav').value = result;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="span7" style="width:400px;height:100px;" id="seriaNav">[{"title":"First Item","href":"first","children":[{"title":"Sub First Item","href":"sub"}]},{"title":"Second Item","href":"home"}]</textarea>
<hr />
<button class="btn btn-primary" onClick="convertNav();return false;">Convert</button>
<hr />
<textarea class="span5" style="width:400px;height:100px;" id="convertedNav"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm now wondering how i completely missed that i needed a for loop.. its late.
using the foreach seams much better!

Comment: Be reminded that for Internet Explorer, `forEach` is only available since IE9. [kangax's ES5 compat-table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Array.prototype.forEach), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

Your jsn variable is an array. You're getting a list of Objects back and you'll need to parse each one. 
Add this after you get jsn back and you'll see an example of retrieving your data.

```
alert(jsn[0].title);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is parsed into an array of objects. With this in mind, your paths to extract information are wrong. For example, you have:

```
if(jsn.title...
```

...whereas there is no `jsn.title`. There is, however, `json[0].title`.

Basically, you're missing a loop, over the objects. After

```
var result = '';

add
```

for (var i=0, len=jsn.length; i

...and in code subsequent to that change all references to `jsn` to `jsn[i]`

And of course close the loop further down.

(Finally, at the risk of being pedantic, `jsn` is not the best name for the var; it's not JSON anymore; it used to be, but now it's parsed, so it's an array. JSON is a string.)

Answer (score 0):

```
[{"title":"First Item","href":"first","children":[{"title":"Sub First Item","href":"sub"}]},{"title":"Second Item","href":"home"}]
```

This is not JSON, this is an array of objects. You don't need to parse this. It's already parsed. It's a javascript object.

You should be able to just parse it like you would a regular object.

```
data[0].title

data[0].children[1].title
```

etc.

Comment: It's a valid JSON. `In JSON, they take on these forms: An array is an ordered collection of values. An array begins with [ (left bracket) and ends with ] (right bracket). Values are separated by , (comma).` http://json.org/

Comment: It's an object. JSON is a string.